# How to make contents alignment in <div>

Tags: html, css

I have a div tag and there are two `<a>` tag inside. I want to place one at the right side and one at the left side.

For example

```
ABC                      PQR
```

How can I do this in mvc html?

Comment: you want us to guess your code structure? Or would you like a proper answer... Please include your code.

Comment: I could find the nswer. provide &nbsp; for white space. is there any other way around

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -2):

`&nbsp;&nbsp;` for white space